# Creating metric filter for Amazon s3 PutObject in amazon cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a metric filter that filters the S3 object put requests and bases on that filter I will create an alarm that if there is no object uploaded in S3 bucket in last 24 hours, it will send an alert.
I also have a different solution that uses the s3 Event notification and dynamodb to send alerts, but I want this to be done through cloudwatch metric filter.
The problem is that I am unable to create a metric filter for a particular bucket. So it scans all the buckets. Here is my filter:

```
{ ($.eventSource = s3.amazonaws.com) && (($.eventName = CopyObject) || ($.eventName = CompleteMultipartUpload) || ($.eventName = PutObject) || ($.eventName = PostObject)) }
```

And here is how the logs are captured for one particular bucket:

```
"eventTime": "2022-07-05T06:50:46Z",
    "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "PutObject",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "bucketName": "my-test-s3-bucket",
        "x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
        "x-amz-server-side-encryption-context":
```

Is there any way I can include only one S3 bucket on my filter pattern? I have tried different ways but it didn't work.

Comment: Luckily after few tries I found the solution:                                                                       { ($.eventSource = s3.amazonaws.com) && ($.requestParameters.bucketName = "my-test-s3-bucket") && (($.eventName = CopyObject) || ($.eventName = CompleteMultipartUpload) || ($.eventName = PutObject) || ($.eventName = PostObject)) }

Answer (score 0):

Luckily after few tries I found the solution:

```
{ ($.eventSource = s3.amazonaws.com) && ($.requestParameters.bucketName = "my-test-s3-bucket") && (($.eventName = CopyObject) || ($.eventName = CompleteMultipartUpload) || ($.eventName = PutObject) || ($.eventName = PostObject)) }
```